# EF Code First: Problem casting ValueObject to string for Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I've been following some tutorials and value objects look great if I can get them working, so hope you guys can help.

I have a class Account containing Value Objects AccountNumber and SortCode (note BaseEntity just has int Id)

```
public class Account : BaseEntity
{
    public Account() => Transactions = new List<StatementTransaction>();

    public BankSortCode SortCode { get; set; }
    public BankAccountNumber AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string BankName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<StatementTransaction> Transactions { get; set; }
    
}
```

BankSortCode and BankAccountNumber are both value types with string conversions defined, e.g.

```
public class BankAccountNumber : ValueObject
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; private set; }

    public BankAccountNumber()
    {
    }

    public static BankAccountNumber For(string accountNumberString)
    {
        if (accountNumberString.Length <= 7 || accountNumberString.Length > 9)
        {
            throw new BankAccountNumberInvalidException(accountNumberString);
        }

        try
        {
            _ = Int32.Parse(accountNumberString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new BankAccountNumberInvalidException(accountNumberString, ex);
        }

        var accountNumber = new BankAccountNumber();
        try
        {
            accountNumber.AccountNumber = accountNumberString;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new BankAccountNumberInvalidException(accountNumberString, ex);
        }

        return accountNumber;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return AccountNumber;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(BankAccountNumber accountNumber)
    {
        return accountNumber.ToString();
    }

    public static explicit operator BankAccountNumber(string accountNumberString)
    {
        return For(accountNumberString);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAtomicValues()
    {
        yield return AccountNumber;
    }
}
```

I intend to hold these in the DB as string fields for the account class, so set up modelBuilder in my DBContext like this:

```
private void ConfigureAccount(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
        .Entity<Account>()
        .Property(a => a.SortCode)
        .HasColumnType("varchar")
        .HasMaxLength(6)
        .HasConversion<string>();

        modelBuilder
        .Entity<Account>()
        .Property(a => a.AccountNumber)
        .HasColumnType("varchar")
        .HasMaxLength(9)
        .HasConversion<string>();
    }
```

However, when I try to add migration, I get the following error:

```
The property 'Account.AccountNumber' is of type 'BankAccountNumber' which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

Am I approaching this in the right way, and how do I overcome the issue I am experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I got it working, copying [Pawel Gerr on Think Tecture](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/improved-value-conversion-support-in-2-1/).

HasConfiguration(howToTransformForInsert, howToTransforForRetrieve):

```
private void ConfigureAccount(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
        .Entity<Account>()
        .Property(a => a.SortCode)
        .HasColumnType("varchar")
        .HasMaxLength(6)
        .HasConversion(sortCode => sortCode.ToString(), sortCodeString => BankSortCode.For(sortCodeString));

        modelBuilder
        .Entity<Account>()
        .Property(a => a.AccountNumber)
        .HasColumnType("varchar")
        .HasMaxLength(9)
        .HasConversion(accountNumber => (string)accountNumber, accountNumberString => BankAccountNumber.For(accountNumberString));
    }
```